# Update array inside another array

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON array that represents a list of objects (people).
every object (every person) has name attribute, image, and an array of numbers.

Example:

```
"people":[  
   {  
      "name":"nunu",
      "image":"image1",
      "numbers":{  
         "total":50,
         "vector":[  
            10,
            20,
            5,
            10,
            5
         ]
      }
   }
];
```

My goal is to update all vectors and append some calculation to each vector.

This is what I tried:

```
this.people = this.people.map((person) => {
      return person.numbers.vector.map((num) => {
        return Math.round(((num / divider) * 100) / 100);
      });
    });
```

The problem is that `people` is being replaced by the numbers in my `vector` and I lose the people data.

How I can update the vectors without making nay change to any other data?

Comment: Use `.forEach()` on the outer array, and just update `person.numbers.vector` for each one.

Comment: You're misusing `.map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [.map() specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it creates a new array, to process top-level list use `.forEach()` instead:

```
this.people.forEach(person => 
  person.numbers.vector = person.numbers.vector.map(num =>
    Math.round(((num / divider) * 100) / 100)
  );
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the new spread operator and something like Babel this becomes trivial:

```
const source = {
  "people": [{
    "name": "nunu",
    "image": "image1",
    "numbers": {
      "total": 50,
      "vector": [
        10,
        20,
        5,
        10,
        5
      ]
    }
  }]
};

const newSource = {
  ...source,
  people: source.people.map(person => {
    return {
      ...person,
      numbers: {
        ...person.numbers,
        vector: person.numbers.vector.map(n => Math.round(((n / 2) * 100) / 100))
      }
    }
  })
};
```

Here is more on the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator.

As a side note, using the spread operator creates a new object and using `map` creates a new array. This way you will always have a new object and can't change the old one. Using `const` with this type of code is also a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
people = people.map((person) => {
    person.numbers.vector =  person.numbers.vector.map((num) => {
        return Math.round(((num / divider) * 100) / 100);
    });
    return person;
});
```

You were returning the vector as the value for person, you need to change the value of vector then return person instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `spread` operator to update person object and save all data. For example, calculate `total` value as sum of nums:

```
 this.people = this.people.map((person) => {
   let total = person.numbers.vector.reduce((prevNum, nextNum) => {
     return prevNum + nextNum;
   });

   return {
      ...person,
      numbers: {
         ...person.numbers,
         total
      }

  }
});
```

At the same way you can change vector values, for example